# react-native-video with remote url play after download entire video file

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

The larger the remote url file size, the significantly longer the loading time before playback.

like html5 video tag, I want it to be played immediately with downloaded part.(streaming)

Any possible solutions?

```
<Video
    ignoreSilentSwitch={'ignore'}
    style={[{ height: 211 }, props.style ? props.style : styles.video]}
    source={{ uri }}
    onEnd={onEnd}
    onLoad={onLoad}
    onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
    onProgress={onProgress}
    onSeek={onSeekVideo}
    paused={paused}
    ref={(ref) =>  videoPlayer.current = ref}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
  />
  <MediaControls
    duration={duration}
    isLoading={isLoading}
    mainColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
    onFullScreen={noop}
    onPaused={onPaused}
    onReplay={onReplay}
    onSeek={onSeek}
    onSeeking={onSeeking}
    playerState={playerState}
    progress={currentTime}
    showOnStart={false}
    fadeOutDelay={10000}
    isFullScreen={isFullScreen}
    onDoubleTab={onDoubleTab}
  >
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: @VáclavRyska I added code